# How to highlight a column in Google Sheets if this column contains dates Mon and Sun where Mon>today and today<Sun

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, conditional-statements, formula

I've created a custom schedule in my Google Spreadsheet broken down onto weeks with Mondays in row 1 and Sundays in row 2.

So far I can highlight only particular day in rows 1 or 2 that equals to today (simple condition 'Date is in the past week').
I need to highlight entire column if Monday>today and today<Sunday.
How to do it via conditional formatting formulas?
Thanks.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output